# Conditional content_tag inline styling

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got the following code:

```
<% content_tag(:h1, :class => ['h1', modifier], :color => '#{partner.color}', :style => 'color: #{partner.color}') do %>
  <%= yield %>
<% end %>
```

`<% modifier %>` & `<% partner.color %>` will return a string or nil.

What I'd like is to check for `partner.color`'s existence and render `:color =>` & `:style =>` only if `partner.color` is not nil.

How can I do this?

Comment: `css class || nil` always returns `css class`. Same with string. What behavior you exactly expect?

Comment: I may not be making that clear enough. `modifier` will either return a string or nil. Same as the others. The behavior I'd like is to not have `:color =>` or `:style =>` if `partner.color` is nil.

Comment: @thatgibbyguy, Whats output of `:style => 'color: #{partner.color}'`, in html if exist `partner.color` right now?

Comment: If `partner.color` exist that will output `style='color: #000000'` else it will output `style=color:`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each of the submitted answers come very close to answering the question and deserve upvotes, however each come with errors. The proper syntax is:

```
<% content_tag(:h1, { :class => ['h1', modifier]}
               .merge( partner ? {
                :color => '#{partner.color}', 
                :style => 'color: #{partner.color}'
               } : {})
              ) do%>
  <% yield %>
<% end %>
```

We start the content tag, then proceed to send in an object `{ :class => []}`. From there we will merge in a new object that will check some logic `.merge({})`.

`merge` will have to take in an object so we first check if our class is available `partner ?` with no need to check its contents. If `partner` exists we pass in the partner parameters in an object, if not we pass in an empty object.

Answer (score 1):

That is just a ruby hash. You could do, for example, something like:

```
content_tag(:h1, {:class => ['h1', modifier]}.merge( partner.color.nil? ? {} : {:color => '#{partner.color}', :style => 'color: #{partner.color}'}))
```

Comment: `undefined method `merge' for ["h1", nil]:Array`

Answer (score 1):

Its totally works, check this one.

```
<%= content_tag(:h1, {:class => ['h1', modifier]}.merge( partner.color.present? ? {:color => "#{partner.color}", :style => "color: #{partner.color}" } : {})) do %>
   <%= yield %>
<% end %>
```